# Additivity false with different log levels, which logger level is used?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, log-level

please consider the follwing snippet:

```
   <AsyncLogger name="com.example.Section" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Logger1" />

   </AsyncLogger>

     <AsyncLogger name="com.example.Section2" level="INFO"/>

    <AsyncRoot level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="Logger1" />
    </AsyncRoot>
```

Am I correct in assuming that Section1 will be logged at warn level.  And Section2 at ALL level (not info)?

UPDATE: I meant warning level or above for Section1.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not correct.

Any events with a level of `WARN` or more specific (`ERROR` or `FATAL`) that are sent to the "com.example.Section" logger will be accepted by that logger and sent to its appenders. Since additivity is `false` for this logger events are not sent to any appenders of its ancestors.

Any events with a level of `INFO` or more specific (`WARN`, `ERROR`, `FATAL`) sent to the logger "com.example.Section2" will be accepted by that logger and sent to its appenders. Since additivity is `true` by default events accepted by this logger will go to the appenders of its ancestors as well, which would only be those of the root logger.

Any events that go to the root logger will be accepted and sent to its appenders regardless of log level since its level is set to `ALL`. As this is the root logger additivity does nothing, there are no ancestors of this logger.

The log4j2 manual has examples and explanations of [additivity](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity) that can help you understand this as well. There are some other questions on stackoverflow about additivity that may also be helpful.

Comment: I said Section2 would be at all level.

Comment: I meant warning level or above for section1.

Comment: I see, then you were correct about section 1, but not about section 2. Please read the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: So he root level does no override the Section2 level?

Comment: No, they are separate loggers they do not override each other.